# Finding intersection points of 2 functions. My method is incomplete.

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions, quadratic-forms

**These are the 2 functions :**

$y = x^{4}-2x^{2}+1$

$y = 1-x^{2} $

**Here's how I solved It :**

$x^{4}-2x^{2}+1 = 1-x^{2}$
$x^{4}-x^{2} = 0$
$x^2(x^2-1)=0$
$x^2-1=0$
$x=\pm \sqrt{1} $

Value of $y$ when $x=1$
$y=1-x^2\\y=1-1\\y=0$

Value of $y$ when $x=(-1)$
$y=1-x^2\\y=1-(-1)^2\\y=1-1\\y=0$

So the intersection points of the 2 functions are $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$.

**The problem**

The problem is when I used a graphing calculator to find the intersection points of the above 2 functions it gave me 3 results instead of 2. They were :
$(-1,0),(0,1),(1,0)$

So what am I missing ? Why don't I get 3 intersection points ?

Best Regards !

Comment: As shown by @PraphullaKoushik , your 4th line should be re-written as such. In that way, 0 is also a root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^2(x^2-1)=0\Rightarrow \text{either } x^2=0 \text{ or } x^2-1=0$

Answer (score 1):

**Functions:**

a.)  y  =  x^4 - 2x^2 + 1

b.)  y  =  1 - x^2

**Solving:**

x^4 - 2x^2 + 1  =  1 - x^2

x^4 - x^2  =  0

x^2 * ( x^2 - 1)  =  0

**Now set each part equal to 0**

x^2  =  0

x  =  0

x^2 - 1  =  0

x  =  +/-1

**Now plug in each value of x to get the corresponding value of y**

**X  =  0**

y  =  1 - (0)^2

y  =  1

Intersection at (0,1)

**X  =  1**

y  =  1 - (1)^2

y  =  1 - 1

y  =  0

Intersection at (1,0)

**X =  -1**

y  =  1 - (-1)^2

y  =  1 - 1

y  =  0

Intersection at (-1,0)

**Intersections for function a and b are:**

(0,1)

(-1,0)

(1,0)

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 It is advisable to use mathjax on this site.